# Dimension of the subspace of $\operatorname{Hom}(V,V)$ s.t. $TE=ET$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm attempting an old exam question about projections. Earlier in the question we proved that

> If $E$ is a linear map from $V$ to $V$ s.t. $E^2=E$ and if $T$ is another map from $V$ to $V$ then $TE=ET$ iff $\operatorname{Im} E$ and $\ker E$ are $T$-invariant.

The last part of the question asks for the dimension of $W$, the set of all linear transformations $T$ from $V$ to $V$ s.t. $TE=ET.$

Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: what've you thought about for this part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your earlier part, $J = $Im$(E)$ and $K = \ker (E)$ must be $T$-invariant.

Note that $V = J \oplus K$ (why?).  We can therefore construct any satisfactory $T$ as follows: let $T_1: J \to J$ be a linear function.  Let $T_2 : K \to K$ be a linear function.  Define $T = T_1 \oplus T_2 : J \oplus K \to J \oplus K$.

What is the dimension of $\operatorname{Hom}(J,J)$?  How about $\operatorname{Hom}(K,K)$?  What does this tell us about the dimension of $W = \operatorname{Hom}(J,J) \oplus \operatorname{Hom}(K,K)$?

Comment: Dim Hom(J,J)=(rkE)^2, Dim Hom(K,K)=(nulE)^2, so the dimension of the direct sum is (rkE)^2+(nul)^2 by the dimension formula ( since the intersection is zero).